# Brox Dense Optical Flow tracker error 'EFilterIncompatibleSize'

Tags: c++, image-processing, opticalflow

I am using the Linux 64-bit non-GPU executable dense optical flow tracker provided by Thomas Brox (available here: < http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/brox/code.html >). I've followed the instructions there and correctly set up a .bmf file listing my own custom images for tracking. I have installed the library file included with this executable. Things seem to be working correctly, and the tracking executable starts to process my frames much like it does for the example frames included with it.

However, shortly after starting to process, I get this error:

```
Exception EFilterIncompatibleSize: Initial container size: 2232  Resulting container size: 2592
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'EFilterIncompatibleSize'
Aborted
```

I can't find any references to this error on message board posts or anywhere else online. Has anyone else used Brox's tracker successfully on your own image files? If so, can you shed any light on this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging and contacting the author, it turns out that this error is caused when images of different sizes are given to the tracker. The container size is related to the pixel dimensions of the images. In my case, I believed that all of my images had identical dimensions since they were outputs from a cropping program. However, some of the regions which were being automatically cropped were very close to the image boundary, and so the cropping truncated them, resulting in smaller cropped regions by a few pixels here and there. If you encounter this error, this is the first thing I would check.